# Ruby - Split a String to retrieve a number and a measurement/weight and then convert numberFo

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split, match

I need to split a string, for food products, such as "Chocolate Biscuits 200g"

I need to extract the "200g" from the String and then split this by number and then by the measurement/weight.

So I need the "200" and "g" separately.

I have written a Ruby regex to find the "200g" in the String (sometimes there may be space between the number and measurement so I have included an optional whitespace between them):

```
([0-9]*[?:\s ]?[a-zA-Z]+)
```

And I think it works. But now that I have the result ("200g") that it matched from the entire String, I need to split this by number and measurement.
I wrote two regexes to split these:

```
([0-9]+)
```

to split by number and

```
([a-zA-Z]+)
```

to split by letters.

But the .split method is not working with these.
I get the following error:

```
undefined method 'split' for #MatchData "200"
```

Of course I will need to convert the 200 to a number instead of a String.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thank you!

UPDATE:
I have tested the 3 regexes on http://www.rubular.com/.

My issue seems to be around splitting up the result from the first regex into number and measurement.

Comment: Not clear what `([0-9]*[?:\s ]?[a-zA-Z]+)` does. Is it okay to have no numbers? Why do you want a question mark or a colon? The alternative between `\s` and ` ` is redundant.

Comment: It looks for any amount of numbers, optionally followed by a space and then any amount of letters

The     [?:\s ] part is for an optional whitespace, I found it in a different thread to have an optional value in the regex.

Comment: Thank you. I had a look earlier but it doesn't help me with splitting up the result from the initial regex.

Comment: "But the .split method is not working with these." - because you're using .split on a MatchData, not a string. Which is clearly stated in the error message.

Comment: You've made the assumption that [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-strip) is required, which is premature and, imo, not the best approach. You'll get better answers and a wider range of answers by focusing on what you want to achieve, rather than on how you can implement a particular approach.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: this balance is tricky to achieve. When transforming from "XY question", where to stop in order not to become a "gimme teh codez"? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way among many is to use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regex. See the last sentence of the doc concerning the treatment of capture groups.

```
str = "Chocolate Biscuits 200g"

r = /
    (\d+)          # match one or more digits in capture group 1
    ([[:alpha:]]+) # match one or more alphabetic characters in capture group 2
    /x             # free-spacing regex definition mode           

number, weight = str.scan(r).flatten
  #=> ["200", "g"]
number = number.to_i
  #=> 200
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this seems to work! :)
Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in ruby, but I guess that the following code does the deal

```
myString = String("Chocolate Biscuits 200g");

weight = 0;

unit = String('');

stringArray = myString.split(/(?:([a-zA-Z]+)|([0-9]+))/);

stringArray.each{
    |val|
    if val =~ /\A[0-9]+\Z/

        weight = val.to_i;
    elsif weight > 0 and val.length > 0

        unit = val;
    end
}

p weight;

p unit;
```